# GhostScript convert pdf to text

Tags: macos, ghostscript

I want to convert a pdf file containing tables (swimming competitions results) to a text file. The purpose is to use the text file as data file for data processing.

The configuration I Am running is:

- MacBook Pro
- gs version 9.56.1
- OS Ventura 13.1.

I found on forums the following command line:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=txtwrite -dFirstPage=3 -dLastPage=119 -sOutputFile=output.txt -q swimresults.pdf -c quit
```

This gives me text file as expected but only for the last page `-dLastPage`.

Is there something I am doing wrong to get all pages converted to TXT? or is there something I should check about the input PDF file that prevents the actions to be done properly?

Comment: Either use the %d syntax to get each page in a separate file, or use the most recent code. There was a regression in 9.56 where we (deliberately) altered the behaviour, but then altered it back again after complaints.

Answer (score 1):

Your programme code via command line calling that library should be working so your right to question why not.
From Artifex comment:-

> You should be aware that many PDF files will not produce the text you expect for a number of reasons. The only reliable form is a PDF where all the fonts have ToUnicode CMaps (which are optional).

PostScript or PCL input is less likely to work.

In my test that program command is correct (but could be improved syntactically i.e. simplified). If you need a password **used in decoding (i.e. reading not writing) encrypted PDF files** add -sPDFPassword="MyPassword"

To see progress (for debugging) we can run like this

```
gs -sDEVICE=txtwrite -dFirstPage=3 -dLastPage=119 -o output2.txt colours.pdf

GPL Ghostscript 10.0.0 (2022-09-21)
Copyright (C) 2022 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 3 through 4.
Page 3
Page 4
```

Result

```
           Pantone 100            Pantone 101           Pantone 102            Pantone 103             Pantone 104               Pantone 105             Pantone 106
           Pantone 108            Pantone 109           Pantone 110            Pantone 111             Pantone 112               Pantone 113             Pantone 114
           Pantone 116            Pantone 117           Pantone 118            Pantone 119             Pantone 120               Pantone 121             Pantone 122
...
```

And see the result is correct there are 2 pages of text in the programmed output .

Thus the question here is what is the structure of your input, that could be a problem?

Always best to provide a link to any problem input data.

### For the benefit of others

There are many ways text can be imbedded in a PDF and only some are candidates for programmable extraction as text.

Typical errors
Not enough start pages

```
Requested FirstPage is greater than the number of pages in the file: 1
   No pages will be processed (FirstPage > LastPage).
```

File has no text

```
Processing pages 1 through 1000.

Result output.txt 0 bytes (naturally)
```

### Not enough output

```
Processing pages X through Z.
```

[edit]
I had said that my first attempt to see why a page may fail was

> The litmus test for, "Should a page be output as text"? Is usually can it "Read Aloud" to a blind person, without garbage words!

Because sometimes in first browse you may not be able to simply copy and paste, and from comments, the point rightly made, was that is not a guarantee / infallible as in many cases including GhostScript that is not the system criteria they use.

See related comment

> There's no reasonably reliable way to tell if it will work, none at all. Even within a single file or page you can't tell, some text might work while other text doesn't.

at this point you may need to try raster to vector OCR **as a very last fall back resort**

```
rem ensure tessdate folder is in environment for the language files
set TESSDATA_PREFIX=C:\Apps\PDF\tesseract\tessdata

gs -sDEVICE=ocr -r300 -sOCRLanguage="eng" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1000 -o c:\data\testtext\gs-ocr.txt image.pdf
```

[image]

Comment: Reading aloud isn't really a good test, accessible PDF files (PDF-UA) can work fine with text to speech readers if the file contains marked content, but txtwrite doesn't use marked content, it uses the marking operators, so may not work.

Comment: There's no reasonably reliable way to tell if it will work, none at all. Even within a single file or page you can't tell, some text might work while other text doesn't

Comment: No not really, OCR is a last ditch effort, but it will work where other approaches simply can't. You might try bumping the resolution up because 300 dpi will give better results with small text, but it will of course be slower. In general higher resolution = more likely to get OCR recognition (though unless your text is really very small 300 dpi should be enough) but at the cost of time.

Comment: Not really, you haven't said what problem you had, also your command line says -sDEVICE=ocr so I'm not clear where pdfwrite is involved.